# Beast websocket idiomatic shutdown?

Tags: c++, boost-beast

I have my C++ program. The main thread creates a new thread that is dedicated to only handling a websocket. This new thread reads and writes using for example boost beast's async_read() calls. It is much like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp where each async call gives rise to another async call.

But what is the idiomatic way to get the main thread to tell the websocket thread to shutdown given that there will likely always be some async read or write call outstanding like an async_read() idle waiting for the server to eventually send data. A shutdown would need to do something like cancel the remaining async_read() without introducing some kind of race condition where the read starts happening just before the cancel.

Comment: Test an atomic flag in `do_accept()` whether or not to continue accepting new connections?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think that's a good idea. Instead, just call `close` on the acceptor, from the correct implicit or explicit strand.

Answer (score 2):

Use `boost::asio::post` to post a lambda to the `io_context` (using the appropriate `strand` if necessary) which calls `cancel` on the underlying `basic_socket`. Pending operations will complete immediately with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`. Inside your completion handler you can check `basic_socket::is_open` to know whether or not you should attempt new asynchronous calls.